# Sum Data in Table by incrementing columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following values in the cells in the below four rows. The fifth row contains the formula

```
Row 1:  3  4   5   6
Row 2:     10  15  7
Row 3:         22  11
Row 4:             23
Row 5:
```

How to construct a SUM formula in Row 5 which can sum R1C2 first and then in next cell sum R1C3+R2C3 then sum R1C4+R2C4+R3C4 and so on!

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If the cells w/o number are empty you can safe add them to the sum. And formula is `=sum(r1c2..r4c2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Romeo Ninov stated is true, if there are no numbers below the desired sum range then just sum the entire range.  If there are and you only want the pattern then:

```
=SUM(B$1:INDEX(B$1:B$4,COLUMN(A:A)))
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAi]6o.png